# Bigquery Resolved vs Unresolved SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

What is the difference between resolved and unresolved sql mentioned here:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this query:

```
SELECT * FROM dataset.view1 JOIN dataset.view2 USING (key)
```

Where `view1` is:

```
SELECT 1 AS key, 'foo' AS y;
```

`view2` is:

```
SELECT 1 AS key, 'bar' AS z;
```

In this case, you can think of the resolved query as a JSON object/proto message containing:

```
{
  "query": "SELECT * FROM dataset.view1 JOIN dataset.view2 USING (key)"
  "views":
  [
    {
      "name": "view1",
      "sql": "SELECT 1 AS key, 'foo' AS y;"
    },
    {
      "name": "view2",
      "sql": "SELECT 1 AS key, 'bar' AS z;"
    }
  ]
}
```

So the resolved query length is the sum of the lengths of the query plus the views. The resolved query length limit is high enough that it generally isn't relevant for standard SQL queries. For legacy SQL queries, though, functions such as `TABLE_DATE_RANGE` are like macros that expand the query to a union of all matched tables, so it's easier to end up with a large resolved query size.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Understood

Comment: So for standard sql ,there is no limit on resolved query size?

Comment: It's 12 MB as well, but you would have to try pretty hard to reach that, e.g. a 1 MB query referencing multiple large logical views.

Comment: Actually I am executing a paramertized standard sql query though google-python client library and passing a query param of 0.5 million customer ids list and the job is breaking.My sql : "SELECT * from temp.customers where customer_id in UNNEST(@cust_ids)

Comment: Is there any other better way to execute this kind of query having huge data inside 'in' operator from my application(python) code?

Comment: You should probably put the customer IDs in a table rather than passing all of them as a query parameter.

Comment: But for creating a table though python code,there also I'll need to pass this huge customer ids list in query param.

Comment: You could run two INSERT queries, or put the IDs in a file on GCS and then load them into a table. You may want to submit a separate question, though--comments aren't a good place for Q&A.